# Will glass still update after a factory reset?

Tags: google-glass

If I factory reset, are the glass update servers still running? Will glass update after a factory reset?

I'm having troubles playing YouTube videos. The gray video screen pops up after a few seconds of loading but then it goes away. I'm thinking factory reset may help but I don't want to get stuck on an old version.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and just tried it. I did a factory reset and it reloaded and started to say it was updating. It took some time to boot again after that.

I checked the settings menu and it showed XE22! All is good.